# Update a users profile information using simple textboxs

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, profile

So I have made a log in system and now I wan't to allow the users to update their information. I thought that this code would work but it did not, here it is:

```
    public partial class Account_Update : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser();
    if (usr.IsApproved == false)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
    var p = Profile.GetProfile(usr.UserName);
    /* Displays all current profile information once the page loads */
    FirstName.Text = p.fName;
    LastName.Text = p.lName;
    Address.Text = p.Address;
    Email.Text = usr.Email;
    Company.Text = p.Company;
}
/* Simple button to take you to the home screen */
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
}

protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser();
    var p = Profile.GetProfile(usr.UserName);
    /* Update all information that the user has changed */
    p.fName = FirstName.Text;
    p.Save();
    p.lName = LastName.Text;
    p.Save();
    p.Address = Address.Text;
    p.Save();
    usr.Email = Email.Text;
    Membership.UpdateUser(usr);
    p.Company = Company.Text;
    p.Save();
    Success.Text = "User Information has been updated";
    /* Redisplaying the updated user information */
    FirstName.Text = p.fName;
    LastName.Text = p.lName;
    Address.Text = p.Address;
    Email.Text = usr.Email;
    Company.Text = p.Company;
  }
}
```

The problem seems to be that whatever I change the text to in the text-box is not changing from what was originally in the text-box. So if initially the users first name was Bob and I change it to Robert when I hit the update button it does not change it to Robert. this seems like a simple fix but I'm sort of lost. So to summarize the main question is how do I update the users information to the new text that the user enters in the textbox.

Comment: What class are you using for the text box? I had a look but I can't find the Web.UI equivalent of a text box. Also, what class is p? (the compiler might be able to infer it, but this human can't lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `!Ispostback` at the page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser();
    if (usr.IsApproved == false)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
    var p = Profile.GetProfile(usr.UserName);
    /* Displays all current profile information once the page loads */
    FirstName.Text = p.fName;
    LastName.Text = p.lName;
    Address.Text = p.Address;
      Email.Text = usr.Email;
      Company.Text = p.Company;
   }
}
```

If you don't use it, alwyas when the info going to the server you will get the olds value.

cheers.

Comment: Ahhh new I was missing something simple! Thank you very much!